# Matching and merging headers in R

Tags: r, matrix, merge, header, match

In R, I want to match and merge two matrices.

For example,

```
> A
     ID   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
  1  ex   3  8  7  6  9  8  4
  2  am   7  5  3  0  1  8  3
  3  ple  8  5  7  9  2  3  1

> B
    col1
  1  a
  2  c
  3  e
  4  f
```

Then, I want to match header of matrix A and 1st column of matrix B.

The final result should be a matrix like below.

```
> C
     ID   a  c  e  f
  1  ex   3  7  9  8
  2  am   7  3  1  8
  3  ple  8  7  2  3
```

*(*My original data has more than 500 columns and more than 20,000 rows.)*

Are there any tips for that? Would really appreciate your help.

*In advance, if the matrix B is like below,

```
> B
     col1 col2 col3 col4
  1   a    c    e    f
```

How to make the matrix C in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
A[, c('ID', B[, 1])]
```

For the second case, you want to use row number 1 of the second matrix, instead of its first column.

```
A[, c('ID', B[1, ])]
```

If `B` is a `data.frame` instead of a `matrix`, the syntax changes somewhat — you can use `B$col1` instead of `B[, 1]`, and to select by row, you need to transform the result to a vector, because the result of selecting a row in a `data.frame` is again a `data.frame`, i.e. you need to do `unlist(B[1, ])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subset:

```
cbind(A$ID, A[names(A) %in% B$col1])
```